# UnityのNavmeshのAgent Radiusの値をスクリプトから変更したい

Tags: unity3d

Unityのnavmeshを利用して経路探索を行う処理を実装しています。
下記のNavigationウィンドウのAgentsタブ内にあるRadius項目をScriptから変更することはできのでしょうか？
[image: navmeshのNavigationのWindow]

迷路を想定しているため、壁はCarveとしており、NavMeshAgentのradiusを変更しても想定した効果は得られず困っています。

よろしくお願いします。